# Unable to open developer console

Tags: developer-console

In my developer edition "Developer Console" is not opening.
When i click on developer console it open the new window but after that window will minimize and it become unresponsive, so browser gives the option to kill the pages.
It's happening with AP1 and AP2 instance.

It started happening after lightning release.

Thanks
Rishav

Comment: Have you recently updated your Java and if not, are you running the latest version of it? You don't say what OS or browser you're using. You might want to try a different browser. I'd also recommend clearing your browser's cache to see if that solves your problem.

Comment: I have installed and configured JDK1.8. I have cleared all cookies and browsing data, i have tried this in all browsers Mozila,IE11, chrome but everywhere same problem is occuring.

Comment: Quick work around - Just right click and open the developer console link into new tab.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the very same problems on Sandboxes.

I have opened Salesforce ticket and they referred me again to this SSE post.
And also to [a similar SSE post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/99258/developer-console-crashing?rq=1).

Jermaine's answer to that post helped for me.

If I copy the URL for the developer console into a new window, it opened in the new window without issue. After that I was able to open it directly as popup window from Salesforce.

Later Salesforce support shared [this knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Why-do-I-receive-a-script-error-when-trying-to-execute-the-Developer-Console&language=en_US) with me.
I believe this should always help.

Knowledge Article Number: 000205278
Description: When I'm trying to open the Developer Console it freezes the browser and, depending on the browser, we can see the following error:

"A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue."

Resolution: The solution would be to reset the IDEWorkspace for the affected user. To do this, please:

1. Open the Developer Console as the affected user.
2. When the error appears, please the "Debug Script" button. If you don't have a "Debug Script" button you'll have to open the Browser's Developer Tools manually (please scroll down to the bottom of this Article for additional information).
3. Move to the 'Network" tab of the browser's Dev Tools.
4. You'll find a number of requests, if you don't, please refresh the browser. We're interested in a request with the following format:
   [image]
5. The 'Id' value is the one we are looking for. Please copy that.
6. Open Workbench. Select "Utilities" and then "REST Explorer".
7. Do a GET request for "/services/data/v29.0/tooling/sobjects/IDEWorkspace/1deQ00000004HmJIAU" - remember to replace the "1deQ00000004HmJIAU" parameter with the "Id" relevant to your org that you obtained in step #5.
8. You will see the content of the affected user's IDEWorkspace.
   [image]
9. Do a DELETE request.
10. Re-open Developer Console

After following these steps the Menus should be available again and the error message should no longer appear.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. One of those answers I wish I could upvote multiple times ;)

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 4):

I just encountered the exact same problem with the Developer Console from Chrome.

Immediately after opening the Developer Console would shrink to a small window and say Loading. Shortly after Chrome would report it as hung, along with the originating window.

In the end I used the Microsoft Edge browser to connect to the same org and open the developer console. It seemed to work without issue. I was then also able to open it from Chrome.

I suspect there was a problem tab it was trying to restore.

Answer (score 1):

I would reset all your internet settings, browser settings and try it on a different machine.  I had the same issue and ended up I have a adware in my google browser.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

If you face this error -> you can alternatively open the developer console by going to this URL :-

```
https://{Your_Org_Url}/_ui/common/apex/debug/ApexCSIPage
```

OR in short

```
/_ui/common/apex/debug/ApexCSIPage
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old thread but the behavior hasn't gone away.  I've found if I grab the title bar on the window and hold it the console will load correctly.