# Developer Console is not loading

Tags: developer-console

When I login to Salesforce and open Developer Console, Window pops up but Says "Loading...". My Salesforce instance is na24. I am able to open Developer Console of my other Developer Edition in the browser. Same behavior is observed in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Comment: My other Developer edition instance is also na24

Comment: Did you try clearing your cache? I also have one on na24 and the developer console is working.

Comment: are you a sys admin (or) have View All Data?

Comment: Yes I have cleared cache.It doesn't help. Also I am sys admin and has View All Data permission.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Below are the steps for resolution Salesforce provided
1. login and open Developer Console by Chrome
2. open Developer tools and select Network
3. reload on Developer Console
Use the following query to get the IDEWorkspace

/services/data/v31.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT id, name from IDEWorkspace

and you would get Id: 1de1a0000014sEWAAY
IsDeleted: false
CreatedDate: 2015-06-18T22:02:05.000+0000
CreatedById: 0051a000000K7Y7AAK
LastModifiedDate: 2015-06-27T01:41:37.000+0000
LastModifiedById: 0051a000000K7Y7AAK
SystemModstamp: 2015-06-27T01:41:37.000+0000
UserId: 0051a000000K7Y7AAK
Name: Default
Content:

ID of IDEWorkspace is "1de1a0000014sEWAAY".
4. login to Workbench and go to REST Explorer
5. do GET for "/services/data/v29.0/tooling/sobjects/IDEWorkspace/1de1a0000014sEWAAY"
You will see the content of IDEWorkspace
6. do DELETE
7. re-open Developer Console
You will see an error. And you will see that menus are available.
8. Create a new workspace as the old workspace as been deleted
Then, Developer Console will work fine.

Comment: how do i execute the query from dev console in chrome? Use the following query to get the IDEWorkspace /services/data/v31.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT id, name from IDEWorkspace

Comment: @textual After pressing F12, you get the developer tools and on refresh of the developer console, you receive the logs in the same window.
This is a query in logs and can be seen if you put a filter on IDEWorkspace. query would be something like - GET /services/data/v38.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT%20Id,%20Name,%20Content%20FROM%20IDEWorkspace%20WHERE%20(Id=%271df280000004E9KAAU%27)%20OR%20 Pull out the Workspace ID from it

Comment: If you do not mind about loosing all of yours (or someone else's) console workspaces, this can be simpler - just run a query via workbench and then delete everything you find.

Comment: I have created an APEX script that does that for you.
https://github.com/pranayjswl007/DevConsoleEnablerApex

Comment: Just had this issue, and the chosen answer was really helpful. However, if you have access to a different user, there is an easier way. Log into the other user's dev console. Query with the tooling API:
`SELECT Id, Name, CreatedBy.Name FROM IdeWorkspace` Delete the rows for the affected user only.

Comment: For anyone struggling with Developer Tools, I found a similar solution and walkthrough at [Developer Console Inoperable Menus](https://cropredysfdc.com/category/salesforce/developer-console/) that only requires the Salesforce Workbench.

Comment: Using the idea of deleting the workspace along with @Wookie88 suggestion, I was able to copy the url into a new tab, then create a New Workspace under the Workspace menu and delete the old workspace in Workspace Manger.

Comment: I am using the "Salesforce Inspector" browser extension to do export with the following SOQL: 
    SELECT Id FROM IDEWorkspace
and then deleting the result with the import option

Comment: @Nic how do I get past the 'INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'IDEWorkspace' is not supported.' part when I perform the SOQL?

Comment: Nvm I found out to get past the 'INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'IDEWorkspace' is not supported.' I needed to enable Tooling API

Comment: wow this is such garbage that we have to do this. I used the Salesforce Inspector Chrome extension for the query and the deletion, since we've used it for similar past workflows, and it worked just fine. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I did face this issue, and based on this answer I could get some insights but not involved Google Dev Tools, maybe by the evolution of Salesforce platform or API.

Comment: For me what did work was going to Workbench, Rest Explorer, did make a GET request for "/services/data/v51.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT id, name from IDEWorkspace", here did use use API version 51. Then I get the ID of IDEWorkspace sObject from the response and use to make another GET request, just for check it this object, "/services/data/v51.0/tooling/sobjects/IDEWorkspace/{ID}", substitute the placeholder for your IDEWorkspace ID. Then, just changed the verb HTTP, for DELETE, and make a request, so the register was deleted it and login again in the console IDE without "Loading..." issue.

Comment: You need to use the Workbench tool for Salesforce :to Use the following query to get the IDEWorkspace (via Rest Explorer):
/services/data/v31.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT id, name from IDEWorkspace: Better explanation is here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386416&type=1

Answer (score 15):

Everytime my Dev Console hangs while loading I do the following:

- copy the url from the Dev Console window
- open new tab in browser's main window
- paste URL there

Hope that works also for you.

**UPDATE:**

Sometimes, this is not enough. The console is loaded but unresponsive due to fact that last opened tab is log that is outdated (older than 24hrs and removed).
Then you need to ignore the fact that console is not fully functional and either close all the tabs or click the tab that is valid (apex class, trigger, anything but outddated log). Then refresh the console/reopen it. Works everytime for me!

Comment: Using the idea of deleting the workspace as suggested by @Suneel, I was able to copy the url into a new tab, then create a New Workspace under the Workspace menu and delete the old workspace in Workspace Manger.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes this occurs when you leave too many tabs open, and like @Wookie88 said, especially when you leave outdated log tabs open. What works for me in this scenario is opening the Dev Console as you normally do, then opening Chrome Dev Tools (or browser JS console) for that window, and running the following JS to close all unnecessary/most tabs (you may have to run script a few times if you have a lot of tabs open):

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("x-tab-inner");
for (i = 0; i <= x.length; i++) {
    var tabCheck = x[i];
    if (tabCheck != null && (tabCheck.innerHTML.includes("Log executeAnon") ||
            tabCheck.innerHTML.includes("TestRun") ||
            tabCheck.innerHTML.includes("@"))) {
        tabCheck.parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling.click();
        console.log(tabCheck);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: When this does not work you may need to delete your existing dev console workspace and create a new one which can be done with Workbench. This issue and resolution is outlined here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000205964&language=en_US

Comment: your link help me :) https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332898&type=1&mode=1

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, connected to my org using Microsoft Edge browser and opened the developer console. It worked without issue. Then I was also able to open it from Chrome. This suggestion was posted by Daniel Ballinger in this URL:

[Unable to open developer console](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71688/unable-to-open-developer-console)