# Developer Console becomes unresponsive

Tags: apex, visualforce, developer-console

When I develop in the `Developer Console`, most of the time it gets stuck and an error message shows, then I have to kill the process. My Browser is chrome.

Why is it crashing? How can I fix it?

> **Error screenshot**

[image]

Comment: [link](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80453/developer-console-is-not-loading)

Comment: Please [edit] your post to be more clear. If you have an error message, *always* post it here ***verbatim***. Screenshots may also be helpful in this circumstance.

Comment: as I get error..mostly when I doing it...I will put soon as I get it...this is not the only case with me most of my colleagues are facing the same problem

Comment: Do you have internet issue and does Chrome (all tabs) freezes during the disconnection phase?

Comment: No there is nothing like that as I said most of my colleagues are facing the same problem @Mahmood

Comment: I highly suggest that you DO NOT develop using the Developer Console.  Use the Force.com Plugin for Eclipse, use Sublime Text or Atom with MavensMate plugin, or one of the many others.  Dev Console is just not on par at all.  I use it mostly for SOQL queries (which often time out), running tests, and debugging.

Comment: you can use aside.io as well.This is purely cloud based and doesn't require any plugins to be installed in your system

Comment: @Samir is it goog?

Comment: goog? I didn't get you

Comment: oh sorry I means is it good??well I am trying it I found good...@Samir

Comment: @dBeltowski I install the MavenMate plugin in the Atom but it's completing tag and IntelliSense is not good though I add a lot plugin if you can help me out with that it would be great