# Opening developer console from drop down fails?

Tags: developer-console

[image]

Fails to open in same window in Classic Experience... it works before and i use to open in same window in different tab , is there any update in salesforce org ??

Comment: Please check the proposed solutions from [Unable to open developer console](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/71688/102)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we are not able to launch `Developer Console` in the new tab of same browser window. However, this seems to be working well with Salesforce Lightning.

So if you want to launch `Developer Console` in the new tab of same window, you can just use the URL as below:

```
https://<yourdoamin>/_ui/common/apex/debug/ApexCSIPage

Example : https://cs00.salesforce.com/_ui/common/apex/debug/ApexCSIPage
```

Comment: Yes , this helped a lot . Thanks for the response !

Answer (score 0):

When it will be opened in new tab, just right click on window and there is one option 'Show as tab'. Click on it and this will be displayed as tab in new window.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before chrome this is happening with Mozilla. But from last week its happening with chrome too.

One alternate solution is you can copy that console url & paste it in new tab of chrome browser.